# How to return the exact address name from google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google map post code doesn't show exact address using Google maps API!  For example if I search a **nw107ns** it shows park royal as `formated_address`  which is a big place while it should show Middlesex center hospital.

Am using Google map API with restrictions to UK only.

Your answers are appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), please note that this API meant to convert complete addresses to lat-lng coordinates. Providing only the postal code and the country will give you the details of the postal code NW10 7NS. To get the address of Middlesex center hospital, you must at least include the name of the establishment on your API request to make it more specific.

Like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Middlesex%20center%20hospital&components=country%3AGB&region=GB&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

When using Geocoding API, make sure to adhere to [Geocoding Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices).

If you are using autocomplete, generally [Place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) will return a list of places matching the user's input. If you input NW10 7NS, the autocomplete will return the the place of type postal code since this matches the user's input. If ever you filter the results by type(e.g establishment), the autocomplete will only return places with names or addresses that matched the users input. In the case of NW10 7NS, the API will not return anything since there's no place of type establishment named "NW10 7NS".

Here's a sample Place Autocomplete implementation you can refer to: https://jsfiddle.net/tzgq6kva/

Comment: Below are my codes i'm using google autocomplete service i can't get well what you want to mean <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
<script>
     const options = { types: ['establishment'],  componentRestrictions: { country: 'uk'}
    };
   let autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('locationsearchto'), options);
   autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', function(){
                                                       console.log(autocomplete1.getPlace());});
</script>

Comment: Thanks for providing that information. Might as well edit your question and add those specific information to make your question clear as to which specific API you are using. Also, if possible, please provide a small reproducible sample that we could work on. It would also help to specify your use case. Are you trying to get all the establishments on that specific post code(NW10 7NS) or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: I have updated my answer to add more information regarding Place autocomplete.